# Salvar id do usuário automaticamente nas entidades com Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

Uso o Doctrine 2 para fazer o mapeamento do banco de dados do meu sistema. A maioria das entidades possui uma chave estrangeira apontando para uma entidade "conta".

Quando um usuário loga no sistema, adiciono o id da conta dele em uma variável de sessão. Em seguida adiciono um SQLFilter nas configurações do Doctrine (bootstrap) dessa forma:

```
$config->addFilter("conta", "\Classes\FiltroConta");
```

Essa instrução adiciona uma condição em todas as consultas que o sistema fizer, algo do tipo

```
SELECT nome FROM pessoas WHERE nome = 'pedro' AND conta = 1
```

A condição `conta = 1` é adicionada automaticamente sempre que o filtro estiver configurado. E o número 1 é o id que está na variável de sessão.

Imagine que para persistir um dado na entidade pessoas eu preciso fazer a seguinte instrução:

```
//Obtem referencia da entidade conta
$conta = $em->getReference('Conta', $SESSION['idConta']);
$pessoa = new pessoas();
$pessoa->setNome('Pedro');
$pessoa->conta($conta);
$em->persisty($pessoa);
$em->Flush();
```

O que busco é uma forma de fazer a referencia a entidade conta  de forma automática, utilizando algo nativo do Doctrine, da mesma forma que o SQLFilter faz nas consultas.

Alguém conhece algo?

Answer (score 0):

Após o `persist` o Doctrine popula o id da entidade:

```
$em->persist($account);
$em->flush();
$account->getId();
```

O `$account->getId()` irá retornar para você o id gerado.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Editei a pergunta para ficar mais clara a necessidade.